# How to get status or details of sended mail using messageId in nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, google-api, nodemailer

Here is the code for sending email using nodemailer:

```
class SendMailWithAppPass{
    #user
    #appPassword
    #transporter
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    constructor(userEmail, appPassword){
        this.#user = userEmail,
        this.#appPassword = appPassword,

        this.#transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host:  'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
            auth: {
                user: this.#user, // generated ethereal user
                pass: this.#appPassword, // generated ethereal password
            },
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            },
        });
    }

    async send(from, to, sub, text, html=null){
        let info = await this.#transporter.sendMail({
            from: `"Automata" <${from}>`, // sender address
            to: to, // list of receivers
            subject: sub, // Subject line
            text: text, // plain text body
            html: html, // html body
        });
        
        if(info){
            console.log(info);
            return info;
        }
    }
}
```

After sending email, I get messageId (`'<1b796af0-d69b-f497-a91c-84d7970cd8b1@gmail.com>'`).
I want to use this messageId to get details of sended email to check if email is bounced or not.